# Is there a pythonic way to inter over two dataframes and compare their rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the two dataframes below:

**df1 # read from a excel spreadsheet**

```
data1 = {'ID':['1','2'],
         'Prod Family Desc':['Install','Maintenance'], 'Prod Family Code':['',''], 
         'Prod Type Desc':['Installation Serice','Maintenance Service'],'Prod Type Code':['',''],
        } 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1) 
print(df1)
```

**result df1:**

```
  ID Prod Family Desc Prod Family Code       Prod Type Desc Prod Type Code
0  1          Install                   Installation Serice
1  2      Maintenance                   Maintenance Service
```

**df2 # It is the result of a SQL query**

```
data2 = {'Prod Class':['F','F','T','T'],
        'Prod Desc':['Install','Maintenance','Installation Serice','Maintenance Service'],'Prod Code':['2525','2534','H123','H321']
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2) 
print(df2)
```

**result df2:**

```
  Prod Class            Prod Desc Prod Code
0          F              Install      2525
1          F          Maintenance      2534
2          T  Installation Serice      H123
3          T  Maintenance Service      H321
```

What is the best way to assign the ***values*** of **Prod Family Code** and **Prod Type Code** from df2 to ***column*** **Prod Family Code** and **Prod Type Code** on df1?

***I'm doing this way:***

```
stype = df2.loc[df2['Prod Class'] == "T"] 

family = df2.loc[df2['Prod Class'] == "F"]

for i, concaterow in df1.iterrows():
    for j, styp in stype.iterrows():

        if (concaterow['Prod Type Desc'] == styp['Prod Desc']):
            df1.loc[i,'Prod Type Code'] = styp['Prod Code']

    for j, scat in family.iterrows():
        if (concaterow['Prod Family Desc'] == scat['Prod Desc']):
            df1.loc[i,'Prod Family Code'] = scat['Prod Code']

print(df1)
```

There result is as expected:

```
  ID Prod Family Desc Prod Family Code       Prod Type Desc Prod Type Code
0  1          Install             2525  Installation Serice           H123
1  2      Maintenance             2534  Maintenance Service           H321
```

Is there any pythonic way to this kind of operation?

#### #

**Edit with the answer for @FatihAkici question.

@FatihAkici - As df2 is the result of an SQL query, my expected result is the latest value inserted in the table. So, given the df2 as follow:

````
data2 = {'Prod Class':['F','F','F','T','T'], 'Prod Desc':['Install','Maintenance','Install','Installation Serice','Maintenance Service'],'Prod Code':['2525','2534','2536','H123','H321'] } ```

The expected result would be: 
```ID Prod Family Desc Prod Family Code Prod Type Desc Prod Type Code 
 0 1  Install          2536             Installation Serice H123 
 1 2 Maintenance       2534             Maintenance Service H321
````

Comment: you generally don't want to iterate over dataframes, you want to join them in some way. check out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: What is your expected output if there are duplicates in your df2, such as `'Prod Desc':['Install', 'Maintenance', 'Install', 'Installation Serice', 'Maintenance Service']` and `'Prod Code':['1','2','3','4', '5']`

Comment: Can you add this to your post? I can't read and understand.

Comment: Waiting for you to format your answer properly so I can help you.

Comment: @FatihAkici format answer added to the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `pd.DataFrame.assign` and `pd.DataFrame.merge`:

```
df1.assign(**{
    "Prod Family Code" : df1.merge(df2, left_on = "Prod Family Desc", right_on = "Prod Desc")["Prod Code"],
    "Prod Type Code"   : df1.merge(df2, left_on = "Prod Type Desc", right_on = "Prod Desc")["Prod Code"]})
```

> In your example your dataframe df1 contains 2 empty columns `Prod Family Code` and `Prod Type Code` which receive the results, but it is not a requirement for this method

Comment: I appreciate your time to try to help me with that.
Is the code that you posted suppose to change the original df1?
When I run this code and them print the df1 nothing change. May I missing something?

Comment: You welcome. It's not suppose to change the df1. To do so, just add `df1 = df1.assign(..)`

Comment: This solution worked when I have no duplicate description on df2, I tested with a scenario where I have a duplicate description in df2(see the edited df2 in the post) and its overwrite the maintenance Prod Code with the second Install prod code. I will try to do some adjustment to your code to try fix that.

Comment: If you want to keep the number of rows of df1, just add `how='left'` in each merge

Answer (score 0):

I believe a merge can accomplish what you're looking for

```py
df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['Prod Family Desc'], right_on=['Prod Desc'])
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. When I run the merge the df1 doesn't change with the values for Prod Code. Also, I need to consider the Prod Class when assign the values to Prod Code because the database can have the same description for Family and Type.